# Deploying website to an external test server with Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, testing, web-deployment, eclipse-pdt

I need an effective way to automatically push changes made in Eclipse to a test web server. These are all PHP changes. I am thinking SCP or FTP would be great with an easy to use plugin, but I would be open to other suggestions.

**Background**

At my company, we have Windows development machines, but the only way to test the PHP is to push the code over to a Linux machine that is running an Apache installation. Normally, I would just test locally, using WAMPServer or XAMPP, but I just started with the company and their code base is full of OS specific code (one day we will fix that!).

I have currently setup Git on my machine and I simply commit everything over to a bare repo on the test server. Then I have a post-receive hook that forces a pull into the actual Apache web accessible folder.

This git setup works fine, but I really don't like polluting the blame log with useless commits (i.e. I added a comma to line X in javascript). Things like that are not useful to other developers.

In the end, I won't be pushing from my test server anyway. Instead, I'll be pushing from my Windows machine to a central git server for our team (once I get it set up), so I'm not really sure we should be using version control to deploy to the test web server. It seems like using an SCP or FTP plugin would make the most sense.

**Question Restated**
Are there any Eclipse plugins that could automatically SCP/FTP to a directory on file save? I've searched the Eclipse market place and I am really not sure where to go with this.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the Remote System Explorer  plugin for Eclipse: http://eclipse.org/tm/

Comment: I took a look at it after your suggestion. It seems pretty robust for my needs. Shamil, do you know if it has just a simple way to SCP on save? What I don't want is something that forces me to edit remote files, since I am not keen on dealing with network issues while editing. Thanks!

Comment: I am accepting this answer, because it was helpful. but I just want to say that I ended up just using eGit. I will squash down the commits before moving it to a central code repository.

However, I really appreciate the suggestion of the Remote System Explorer plugin.